# select various options from drop down box in vba

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

How can I change the option for `Customer` dropdown menu as shown in the HTML sample below and then click submit?

I need to change the selected value from:

```
Diamond State Generation Partner (Brookside) (LVG- QFTP-RC)
```

To

```
Diamond State Generation Partners (Red Lion) (LVG- QFTP-RC)
```

and then click submit.

---

**Attempts:**

My attempts are shown below.

on the following line:

```
   MyBrowser.document.querySelector("option[value=1745]").Selected = True
```

error That yielded

> "Run-time error ' -2147352319 (80020101)': Method ' querySelector' of
>   object 'JScriptTypeInfo' failed.

---

**Code:**

```
Sub daily()
    Dim HMTLDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer
    Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
    Dim MYURL As String
    '  website
    MYURL = "website"
    Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
    MyBrowser.Silent = True
    MyBrowser.navigate MYURL
    MyBrowser.Visible = True
    Do
    Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
    ' user login and password
    HTMLDoc.all.user_login.Value = "username"
    HTMLDoc.all.user_password.Value = "password"
    HTMLDoc.forms(0).submit
    While MyBrowser.Busy Or MyBrowser.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    ' click reports
    HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("menuitem")(1).Click
    While MyBrowser.Busy Or MyBrowser.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    'click Billing Analysis Report (Industrial)
    HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("firstlink")(0).Click
    'click to submit to get to billing analysis report
     With MyBrowser.document
    .querySelector("select[name=vsCustKy]").Click
     'I receive the error message on the next line below
    .querySelector("option[value=1745]").Selected = True
   .querySelector("select[name=vsCustKy]").FireEvent "onchange"
     End With
    HTMLDoc.forms(0).submit

End Sub
```

Full HTML:

```html
</SCRIPT>
<LINK rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.conectiv.com/cpd/cpd_stylesheet.css">
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="#ffffff" leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" topmargin="0" background="https://www.conectiv.com/images/big_c_bg.gif" bgproperties="fixed" vlink="#1f969b" link="#1f969b" onLoad="window.query_form.vsReportMonth.focus();">
<!-- Begin: CPD Navigation Header  -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
   <td nowrap valign="bottom"><a href="https://www.delmarva.com"><img src="https://webapps.delmarva.com/images/delmarva_logo.png" border="0" align="middle" alt="Delmarva Power"></a></td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- End: CPD Navigation Header  -->
<TABLE border="1" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bordercolor="#cccccc">
<TR>
<td colspan="1" align="center">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
         <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap>
<a href="gso_etrader_main?vsCurrUser=2753" class="menuitem">Trader Home</a><span class="body"> | </span>
<a href="gso_list_etrader_transaction?vsCurrUser=2753" class="menuitem">Transaction</a><span class="body"> | </span>
<a href="gso_list_etrader_reports?vsCurrUser=2753" class="menuitem">Reports</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</td>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>
<CENTER>
<BR>
<TABLE WIDTH=500 CELLSPACING=0>
<TR>
<TH VALIGN=TOP ALIGN=LEFT>
<FONT COLOR="BLUE" FACE="Arial, Helvetica" SIZE="4">
<B>INPUT THE MONTH & YEAR :</B>
</FONT>
</TH>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<FORM ACTION="gso_billing_analysis_report" METHOD="POST" NAME="query_form" onSubmit="return verify_entries();">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="vsCurrUser" VALUE="2753">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="vsTransactionName" VALUE="INTER_BILLING_ANALYSIS_REPORT">
<TABLE WIDTH=500 CELLSPACING=0>
<TR>
<TD>
<TABLE WIDTH=500 BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=0>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=TOP>
<TABLE WIDTH=500 CELLSPACING=0>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN=LEFT COLSPAN=2>
<FONT COLOR="BLUE" FACE="Arial, Helvetica" SIZE="2">
&nbsp;
</FONT>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD WIDTH=200 ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=CENTER>
<FONT COLOR="BLACK" FACE="Arial, Helvetica" SIZE="2">
<B>MONTH :&nbsp;</B>
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD WIDTH=300 ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=CENTER>
<SELECT NAME="vsReportMonth">
<OPTION VALUE=1>January
<OPTION VALUE=2>February
<OPTION VALUE=3>March
<OPTION VALUE=4>April
<OPTION VALUE=5>May
<OPTION VALUE=6>June
<OPTION VALUE=7>July
<OPTION SELECTED VALUE=8>August
<OPTION VALUE=9>September
<OPTION VALUE=10>October
<OPTION VALUE=11>November
<OPTION VALUE=12>December
</SELECT>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN=LEFT COLSPAN=2>
<FONT COLOR="BLUE" FACE="Arial, Helvetica" SIZE="2">
&nbsp;
</FONT>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD WIDTH=200 ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=CENTER>
<FONT COLOR="BLACK" FACE="Arial, Helvetica" SIZE="2">
<B>YEAR :&nbsp;</B>
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD WIDTH=300 ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=CENTER>
<FONT COLOR="BLACK" FACE="Arial, Helvetica" SIZE="2">
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="vsReportYear" VALUE="2018" SIZE=4 MAXLENGTH=4>
</FONT>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN=LEFT COLSPAN=2>
<FONT COLOR="BLUE" FACE="Arial, Helvetica" SIZE="2">
&nbsp;
</FONT>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD WIDTH=200 ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT COLOR="BLACK" FACE="Arial, Helvetica" SIZE="2">
<B>CUSTOMER :&nbsp;</B>
</FONT>
</TD>
<TD WIDTH=300 ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=TOP>
<FONT COLOR="BLACK" FACE="Arial, Helvetica" SIZE="2">
<SELECT NAME="vsCustKy">
<OPTION SELECTED VALUE=1705>Diamond State Generation Partner (Brookside) (LVG- QFTP-RC)
<OPTION VALUE=1745>Diamond State Generation Partners (Red Lion) (LVG- QFTP-RC)
</SELECT>
</FONT>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN=LEFT COLSPAN=2>
<FONT COLOR="BLUE" FACE="Arial, Helvetica" SIZE="2">
&nbsp;
</FONT>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN=CENTER COLSPAN=2>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Continue">
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN=LEFT COLSPAN=2>
<FONT COLOR="BLUE" FACE="Arial, Helvetica" SIZE="2">
&nbsp;
</FONT>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</FORM>
</CENTER>
<!-- Begin: CPD Navigation Footer  -->
<tr>
<td colspan="1" align="center">
   <table border="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
         <td align="center"><span class="caption">Copyright: 2018 Delmarva Power. All rights reserved</span></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</td>
</tr>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: @QHarr the duplicated error message has been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is due to missing the `''` to surround the number. There is also a form to navigate.

```
MyBrowser.document.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).querySelector("option[value='1745']").Selected = True
```

You may need to ensure there is a wait before attempting to select. Traditionally a

```
While MyBrowser.Busy Or MyBrowser.Busy.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

before is good and after any click events.

You can also use a loop to wait until element is present, with time out.

```
Const WAIT_TIME_SECS As Long = 5
Dim t As Date, ele As Object
t = Timer

Do
    DoEvents
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ele = MyBrowser.document.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).querySelector("option[value='1745']").
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Timer - t > WAIT_TIME_SECS Then Exit Do
Loop While ele Is Nothing
If Not ele Is Nothing Then ele.Selected = True
```

Comment: yeah I did notice that a wait before attempting to select is good. Thanks for your help on this issue, I am now stuck on copy and pasting between workbooks with data if you could please help.

Comment: Is this for a new question? Or scraping above?

Comment: new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009138/daily-task-automation-copy-paste-2-cells-from-1-workbook-into-another-workbo

Comment: I've accepted your answer, i don't remember if this is the one i used as you answered a couple of times but since you did correctly answer it I've chosen your answer. thanks @QHarr!