# daily task automation - copy & paste 2 cells from 1 workbook into another workbook last row

Tags: vba, excel

So I receive a daily data excel workbook that has two cells of data I need to keep in a folder and save it as todays date - 1. So for example, if today is 8-24-18, I receive 8-23-18 data.

I then need to open another file that has all the monthly data. I then have to unhide cells in the file that has all the monthly data then paste the two values from the daily data excel into the monthly data workbook and hide back rows to copy a graph into an email.

The issue with my current macro is it static and won't paste data on the last row of the monthly data workbook. I can get the macro to work by changing the range cell but I would like to find another way.

I currently use:

```
Sub CopyCellToNewWorkBook1
Range ("A1"). Copy Workbooks ("Book1").Worksheet ("Sheet1").Range("D27")
End Sub  

Sub CopyCellToNewWorkBook2
Range ("A2"). Copy Workbooks ("Book1").Worksheet ("Sheet1").Range("F27")
End Sub
```

To copy and paste from one specific cell in one workbook to another specific cell in another workbook. My question is how to I copy the one specific cell and then have the code paste to the next available cell or last cell in the column as I have to change the range daily for this to work.

Updated code with image

```
Sub CopyPasteBetweenWorkbooks()
Dim wbCopy As Workbook
Dim wbPaste As Workbook
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsPaste As Worksheet

    Set wbCopy = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx")
    Set wsCopy = wbCopy.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set wbPaste = Workbooks("Book2.xlsx")
    Set wsPaste = wbPaste.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With wsPaste
        wsCopy.Range("A1").Copy Destination:= _
        .Range("C" & .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1)

        wsCopy.Range("B1").Copy Destination:= _
        .Range("F" & .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Data:

[image]

Comment: `Dim last_row&: With Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1"): last_row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1: End With` Same goes for `F` column.

Comment: @QHarr thanks for the additional advice, i'll keep that in my for future posts. how do i open the code tags in the question to put my code?

Comment: You either indent everything by at least 4 spaces. Or as I did, select all your code then when highlighted press Ctrl + K.